# How much of a Stern-Gerlach apparatus do you need to constitute a measurement?

Tags: quantum-spin

As I understand it a Stern-Gerlach experiment just applies a non-uniform magnetic field onto a beam of particules. In so doing, it changes the orientation of the particules (first?), and then bends their trajectories towards one of 2 possible paths.

But is there some kind of threshold that constitutes a Stern-Gerlach measurement? Since the spin has no amplitude, it is not affected by how strong the device is. But is there a minimum level of magnetic interaction that's required?

I am particularly puzzled by the fact that when you chain SG devices, the spin orientation of particules seems to remain unchanged between the devices, while they necessarily go through some small non-uniform magnetic field in between the experiments.

Comment: Compare the magnetic field in one SG apparatus with the non-uniformity of the background magnetic field in your lab. Contemplate on how many orders of magnitude they differ by. Realize there is not much to puzzle on.

Comment: @JonCuster: I understand that everybody takes it for granted. I'm just wondering where in the theory does the magnitude of the field matter. How would one design a orientation-changing device: how long? how strong? These are legitimate questions.

Comment: The spin "amplitude" is not affected by the strength of the magnetic field, but the force on the particle is. The stronger the field the stronger the force, and in consequence also the curvature of the beam trajectory. The field has to be at least so strong that you can discriminate the two beams at your detector.

Comment: @Sentry: yes but the amplitude of the split is different from the orientation, most of the SG experiments are concerned with the orientation of the spin. What I want to know is how much of a field you need to change the orientation of the spin.

Comment: Do you understand the interaction between a spin and a magnetic field? What is the Hamiltonian? What does that mean for the time dependent dynamics of the spin? Can you make a connection to what is happening in an MRI machine?